# Algorithmic problem of wordlist generation

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, word-list

I want to generate x number of variants of an address, but with a list of predefined symbols.

```
adress = "RUE JEAN ARGENTIN"
a_variants = ["À","Á","Â","Ä","Ã","Å"]
e_variants = ["É","È","Ê","Ë"]
i_variants = ["Ì","Í","Î","Ï"]
u_variants = ["Ù","Ú","Û","Ü"]
r_variants = ["Ŕ","Ŗ"]
o_variants = ["Ò","Ó","Ô","Ö","Õ"]
s_variants = ["Ś","Š","Ş"]
n_variants = ["Ń","Ň"]
d_variants = ["D","Đ"]
```

Example of output

```
# RUE JEAN ARGENTINS
# ŔUE JEAN ARGENTINS
# ŖUE JEAN ARGENTINS
# RÙE JEAN ARGENTINS
# RÚE JEAN ARGENTINS
# RÛE JEAN ARGENTINS
# RÙE JEAN ARGENTINS
# RÜE JEAN ARGENTINS
# ....
# ŖUE JEAN ARGENTÌNS
# ....
# ....
# ŖÛÉ JÉÀŇ ÀŖGÈNTÏŇŞ
# ....
```

I don't especially want a code answer in python or anything, but mostly an algorithmic idea to achieve this. Or even a mathematical calculation to find the number of possible variations.

**Thank you very much**

Comment: How are you representing the variations in your data? Is it hardcoded, or can it change at runtime?

Comment: Only the address can change, the variations are hardcoded

Comment: When you say `x`, do you mean all? Or a number specified by the user? Do you want the combinations to appear some specific order? Or random?

Comment: Calculating the number of variations is easy and fast. Generating all the variations is extremely costly and slow. But both can be done.

Comment: To get an idea of how to generate suppose that you N places with variations and all variations have the same lengths 10. Then you need to generate all numbers with N digits. So start from zero and increment by 1. You have different lengths, but it’s not difficult to handle. In python, you can use `itertools.product`.

Comment: it should be something like `((number of items in a_variants + 1) * number of chars A in text) * ((number of items in e_variants + 1) * number of chars E in text) * ....`

Comment: @Berthur Yes I mean all, no need to specify. And in order as in the example, starting from the first character until the last.

Comment: @AskoldIlvento Thank you for the answer and the tool, I will see to integrate this and the operating mode

Comment: @furas thank you! I had thought of something in style but I was not sure

Comment: because you still can use original `R`, original `U`, etc.

Comment: BTW: if you try it for shorter text and smaller number of variations then you can easy generate manually all variation on paper and count it - and compare it with number from computer - ie. `RD` gives 8 variations (9 versions - original)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like:

- first `R` has `3` versions (`r_variants` + original `R`)
- next `U` has `5` versions (`u_variants` + original `U`)
  etc.

and you have to multipicate all values

```
(number of items in r_variants + 1) * (number of items in u_variants + 1) * ....
```

If you count repeated chars in text then you can reduce it to

```
((number of items in a_variants + 1) * number of chars A in text) * ((number of items in e_variants + 1) * number of chars E in text) * ....
```

But in code I will use first method:

```
address = "RUE JEAN ARGENTIN"

variation = {
'A': ["À","Á","Â","Ä","Ã","Å"],
'E': ["É","È","Ê","Ë"],
'I': ["Ì","Í","Î","Ï"],
'U': ["Ù","Ú","Û","Ü"],
'R': ["Ŕ","Ŗ"],
'O': ["Ò","Ó","Ô","Ö","Õ"],
'S': ["Ś","Š","Ş"],
'N': ["Ń","Ň"],
'D': ["D","Đ"],
}

result = 1

for char in address:
    if char in variation:
        result *= (len(variation[char]) + 1)
        
print(result)
```

Result:

```
37209375   # 37 209 375
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can substract `1` to skip original version `"RUE JEAN ARGENTIN"`

```
37209374   # 37 209 374
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you use shorter text and smaller number of variation then you can easly generate all version on paper (or display on screen) and count them - and check if calculation is correct.

For example for `RN` it gives 8 variation (9 versions - original)

You can use `itertools.product()` to generate all versions

```
import itertools

for number, chars in enumerate(itertools.product(['R', "Ŕ","Ŗ"], ['N', "Ń","Ň"]), 1):
    print(f'{number} | {"".join(chars)}')
```

Result:

```
1 | RN
2 | RŃ
3 | RŇ
4 | ŔN
5 | ŔŃ
6 | ŔŇ
7 | ŖN
8 | ŖŃ
9 | ŖŇ
```

Comment: you are great thank you! it will help me a lot when I will generate each variation, to see if I have the same result for the total number of possible variations

Comment: I added code which uses `itertools.product()` to generate all vesions for `RN`

Comment: Merci! I was stuck on this problem for quite some time and then you came along. I can't thank you enough

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to implement it is using recursion. However, the number of combinations will be gigantic, so I caution you against using this in any practical situation with long words or lots of combinations of characters. Something like this, in pseudocode:

```
results = [];

function getVariations(str, depth):
    if depth == str.length:
        results.add(str);
        return;

    getVariations(str, depth+1);     // For original letter

    c <- str[depth];
    for v in variations[c]:
        str[depth] <- v;
        getVariations(str, depth+1); // For variations of letter

getVariations(yourString, 0);
```